# How to read and post to facebook conversations in my generic application

Tags: facebook, messenger, facebook-messages

I am trying to implement basic Facebook chat features in my application (I am looking for a generic solution, nothing platform specific). Is there any possibility to read user's (my) conversations with other users and post to them?

I searched through Facebook API and SO but found only deprecated `me/inbox` graph API method, deprecated XMPP Chat API (chat.facebook.com) and Messenger platform API, which seems to support only page-to-user or app-to-user but not the user-to-user conversations.

Comment: no, there is no way to access user to user communications

Comment: @luschn thank you. Sadly, that's what I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public API with the ability to send or read a user-to-user facebook conversation.